# squeeze a non-responsive webpage

Tags: javascript, css

i have this following jsfiddle link

where am trying to squeeze the webpage to show an AD towards right

http://jsfiddle.net/azgjr8k0/

Works well with responsive sites, but in the above given fiddle link. it doesn't squeeze a div with fixed width & non responsive sites.
any way i can do it then let me know

here is the css

```
#test {
  position:fixed;
  width:160px;
  background:blue;
  right:-160px;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
 }
#test.show {
  right:0; 
}
#container{
  margin-right:0;
 -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
 -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
 transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}
#container.squeezed {
  margin-right:160px;
}


javscript/jquery code
  window.onscroll = function () {
    if (pageYOffset > 100) {
      $("#test").addClass("show");
      $("#container").addClass("squeezed");
    } else if (pageYOffset < 100) {
      $("#test").removeClass("show");
      $("#container").removeClass("squeezed");
   }

 }
```

Comment: Fixed positioned elements aren't affected by anything except for the container or something involving that object directly (ex. padding to that element).

Comment: @austinthedeveloper . am talking about fixed width div not position

Comment: My bad, I got thrown off by seeing position:fixed on #test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/azgjr8k0/4/

If you want to set widths on things but have them be responsive, make sure they're set as the max-width.

```
#box{
    width: 100%;
    max-width:500px;
}
```